# C++/ASM - "Operand size conflict", "Improper operand type"

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm trying to write a simple for loop in ASM. I need to access two arrays, which are written outside of the code snippet in C++ (being OrigChars and EncrChars)

```
    char temporary_char;                    

__asm {             
      xor ebx, ebx              
      jmp checkend              

      loopfor: inc ebx                          

      checkend: cmp ebx, len              
      jge endfor1               

      mov bx, word ptr[ebx + OrigChars]
      mov temporary_char, bx //error - "operand size conflict"

      push eax
      push ecx

      movzx  ecx, temporary_char    
      lea    eax, EKey          

      push eax                  
      push ecx

      call encrypt1             
      add esp, 8            

      mov temporary_char, al    

      pop ecx
      pop eax

      mov EncrChars[ebx], temporary_char  //error - "improper operand type"

      jmp loopfor           
}
```

The lines with errors on have been commented above.

In a nutshell, why won't these work for me:

- mov temporary_char, bx // temp_char = OChars [i];
- mov EncrChars[ebx], temporary_char //EncrChars[ebx] = temporary_char;

Comment: Are you sure `mov bx, word ptr[ebx + OrigChars]` doesn't work?  It looks like the only correct one in your bullet-point list of problem insns.  (Btw, see the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for lots of useful links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> mov bx, word ptr[ebx + OrigChars]
> mov temporary_char, bx //error - "operand size conflict"
> ```

Since *temporary_char* is of type *char* you just need to replace BX by BL.
**Better still use `AL` because you're using EBX as an addressing index!**

```
mov al, byte ptr [OrigChars + ebx]
mov temporary_char, al
```

---

> ```
> mov EncrChars[ebx], temporary_char  //error - "improper operand type"
> ```

You can't have 2 memory references in the same instruction. Use an intermittent register:

```
mov al, temporary_char
mov byte ptr [EncrChars + ebx], al
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed both issues, as well as explaining why sufficiently.

Comment: @ozank: If you want to zero out the rest of a reg while loading a byte, use `movzx ebx, byte ptr [mem]` or similar.  There's also a `movsx` that sign-extends.  Sign or zero-extending loads don't cost anything extra (except a couple bytes of code-size), and can avoid partial-register slowdowns from later instructions.  (Or on that insn, on CPUs other than Intel P6 or SnB-families, where partial reg writes have a false dependency on the whole reg.)

Answer (score 0):

`char` type is normally 8-bit in size. `bx` register is 16 bit. This is your mismatch.

Comment: Ok, how do I fix that? Sorry I am a rookie at ASM, would I need to truncate the register or something?

Comment: On the contrary. In the first error your restriction is the destination (`char` type), which is smaller than the source (16-bit register). You should use larger type for your `temporary_char`.

Comment: I changed the type of `temporary_char` to string, but I still get the "improper operand type" down at the bottom.

Comment: string is a totally different type, not compatible with the integer types you're working with. You should use integral type, such as `int`.

Comment: If you only want a char, then rather than moving extra stuff around, refer to the register `bl` (which is the least significant 8 bits of the `ebx` register, just as `bx` is the least significant 16 bits of `ebx`.

Comment: @MartinBonner That's correct, but it won't resolve the second error in `mov EncrChars[ebx], temporary_char`